# Knockout Js - ko.utils.arrayFirst does not work

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, binding

I have the following Knockout code
[my Knockout code](http://jsfiddle.net/B66np/132/)

I try to return the mealName each row 
This function takes the ID of the current availableMeals 
And should return an object

```
self.getMealById = function(id) {
     ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableMeals, function(item) {
         return item.id == id;
     });
};

<span data-bind="text: $root.getMealById(meal.id)"  />
```

For some reason she did not do it, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayFirst` will return an object and you are trying to bind an object to a text value in the input field, which won't work.

If your function was to return a string value, it would work fine, here's the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/B66np/133/

**New function** to get the meal name as a string value, note the `.mealName;` on the end of `arrayFirst`:

```
self.getMealNameById = function (id) {
    var meal = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableMeals(), function (item) {
        return item.id == id;
    }).mealName;

    return meal;
};
```

Also, updated the `data-bind` on the `input` to use the new function: `data-bind="value: getMealNameById(1)"`